# Only require a password for remote desktop but not local use in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, remote-desktop, desktop, remote

Wait! There are similar questions but they are specific to windows 7 and XP.

I want to set up remote desktop on windows 8.1 (easy to do) with a password **BUT**, I want to maintain the convenience of not having to log in at all when I'm using the computer normally/locally. That means no login screen on boot, on wake, or any other mode. (It is fine if it locks the computer out while a client is connected though.) Is this possible?

Comment: What solutions from Windows 7 or XP did you try and at what step did they not work?

Comment: The solution for windows 7 was a registry edit. I don't want to go down that road and take the time and risk when the operating system isn't the same.

Comment: the reason this in NOT implemented in any form in standward windows is that it would create an exploit malware could freely use. As such a user account without a password can only be used from the local console.

Comment: I think we aren't on the same page here. I want a password for remote desktop but no login screen for local use.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is fairly easy but I doubt you are going to like it. *Just use 2 user accounts*.

On the first account don't set a password, the second do set one. Then hit <kbd>windows key</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>  to bring up the run dialog and run `secpol.msc`, this will bring up the "Local Security Policy" screen.

From that screen go to `Securty Settings -> Local Policies -> Security Options` and make sure "Accounts: Limit local account use of blank passwords to console logon only" is set to `Enabled`.

[image]

What that security option does is it blocks RDP connections to users who do not have a password set.

Now you can use the account with no password when you are at home and when you are remote you just log in as the 2nd account that does have a password. Your local screen will become locked while the other user account is logged in.

Comment: You're right. I would not use this solution. There should be abetter way like the automated login that windows 7 has.

Comment: @Arewfawe What [automated login](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/windows7/windows7_auto_logon.htm) are you referring to? You can still configure Windows 8 to [logon automatically](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324737).

Comment: I guess that would work then. The article you linked to was for windows server 2003 btw. Make your post an answer and I'll mark it.